# bag-of-words format from two different list

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word-frequency

I have two lists: `A = [['a','b','c'],['a','b','c']]` and `B = ['a','b','c','a','b','c']`. I would like to convert the list into a bag-of-words format where we have a list of `(token_id, token_count) 2-tuples`. I would like to remain the structure of list A but use list B for counting tokens. The code I use currently is: `corpus = [id2word2.doc2bow(text) for text in texts]` where texts is a dictionary of the A list. So the result I would like to have is the following:

```
BoW = [[(1,2),(2,2),(3,2)],[(1,2),(2,2),(3,2)]]
```

and not like this:

```
BoW = [[(1,1),(2,1),(3,1)],[(1,1),(2,1),(3,1)]]
BoW = [[(1,2),(2,2),(3,2),(1,2),(2,2),(3,2)]
```

**EDIT:** Bad example from my side, the words `'a','b','c'` should be changed to identifiers for that specific word. All `'a'` should be reffered to `1` and all `'b'` to `2` and so on. So if we have two lists `A = [['a','z','c'],['z','b','e']]` and `B = ['a','b','c','a','b','c','z','a','e']`.
The result I would like to have is the following:

```
Bow = [(1,3),(2,1),(3,2)],[(2,1),(4,2),(5,1)]
```

All words will be identified with the same integer. I am creating a corpus (term document frequency) from a dictionary where there are unique ids for each unique word.

Answer (score 0):

A pretty easy way I could come up with is this -

```
A = [['a','b','c'],['a','b','c']]
B = ['a','b','c','a','b','c']
out = []
for ls in A:
    newls = []
    for i,j in enumerate(ls):
        newls.append((i+1,B.count(j)))
    out.append(newls)
print(out)
```

The Output this gives is -

```
[[(1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2)], [(1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from collections import Counter

A = [['a','b','c'], ['a','b','c']]
B = ['a','b','c','a','b','c']

def cvt(lst):
    enum = enumerate(Counter(itertools.chain(*lst)).items())
    return {k: (i+1, c) for i, (k, c) in enum}

def replace(lst, cnt):
    return [replace(x, cnt) if isinstance(x, list) else cnt[x] for x in lst]

print(cvt(A))
print(cvt(B))

cnt = cvt(A)
print(replace(A, cnt))
print(replace(B, cnt))
```

output:

```
{'a': (1, 2), 'b': (2, 2), 'c': (3, 2)}
{'a': (1, 2), 'b': (2, 2), 'c': (3, 2)}
[[(1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2)], [(1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2)]]
[(1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2)]​
```